# I have a Edit text and a save button in my activity, what ever text we enter in the edit text should be saved

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I have an `EditText` and a save `Button` in my `Activity`, whatever text the user enters in the `EditText`, it should get saved when the user clicks on the save(add) `Button`.
And there is a `Load Button` whenever the user clicks on a load `Button` in the `Activity` the saved data should get displayed in a `ListView`.

Update: **I want to save user entered data into an Array and populate the list view with the Array**

here is the code:

```
ArrayList<String> namelist = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, namelist );
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_save);
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
            String n = name.getText().toString();
            namelist.add(n);
            name.setText(" ");

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: post your code which you tried with sharedpreference so that some one can edit it and do you want the saved data any time you get into the app or is it to be flushed each time you open the app?

Comment: @KarthikaPB I have to display all the saved data while the app is running! after the app is closed it may flush away.

Comment: ok please post your code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I got the answer folks! Thanks to every one! for your suggestions!**

I have to use `notifyDataSetChanged();` method to populate the `Listview`

Answer (score 0):

Don't store your values in **SharedPreference**.

use **SQLite** to store the data.

Get all the values in Array from **SQLite** and then display in `Listview`.

Comment: Thank you Harish! can I add data directly to array with out using database! I don't want to store it any where.

Comment: If u add directly into an Array, once only data will display in Listview.

Comment: If u add in Sqlite and then Array means, your old data also will display in Listview

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment, *I have to display all the saved data while the app is running! after the app is closed it may flush away*

-- You can use **static String** inside your activity and you can load your edittext with the string when Load button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, shared preferences is used for another things like username of login, password of login or somethings like that but It is NOT a good practice, use that to save data.

To save data, you can use SQLite or some ORM like GreenDao. Is the best and the fastest way to save and load data in local.

http://greendao-orm.com/documentation/how-to-get-started/
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html